# Group charge periods by MAX and MIN voltage, per device in Power BI

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a large data table containing voltage information for hundreds of remote devices. These devices report voltage every ten minutes, and they are charged daily. Charging can start the previous day and continue over midnight into the next day before being taken off charge.

I want to know, per device, the voltage and timestamp of when the voltage was the highest before the voltage started decreasing (because this indicates it came off charge).

I would also like to know the voltage and timestamp of when it was lowest relative to when it was last at its highest.

The objective is to determine how long each battery lasts after each charge before it stops working/reporting and needs to be charged again.

My many poor DAX/PowerBI attempts are not worth posting for critique. Can anyone assist me in achieving this?

**Desired Results**

```
+--------+------------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
| device |  timestamp_high  |  timestamp_low   | voltage_high | voltage_low |
+--------+------------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|      1 | 03/12/2023 09:36 | 03/12/2023 22:11 | 27.73        | 23.77       |
|      2 | 03/12/2023 05:06 | 03/12/2023 17:41 | 27.75        | 23.44       |
|      3 | 03/12/2023 06:06 | 03/12/2023 22:11 | 27.63        | 26.38       |
|      4 | 03/12/2023 06:36 | 03/12/2023 23:02 | 27.45        | 23.45       |
|      1 | 03/12/2023 23:00 | 04/12/2023 23:11 | 28.73        | 23          |
+--------+------------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

**Example Data**

```
+--------+---------------------+---------+------------+----------+
| device |      timestamp      | voltage |    date    |   time   |
+--------+---------------------+---------+------------+----------+
|      1 | 03/12/2023 09:36:00 | 27.73   | 03/12/2023 | 09:36:00 |
|      1 | 03/12/2023 10:36:00 | 27.09   | 03/12/2023 | 10:36:00 |
|      1 | 03/12/2023 18:18:00 | 25.09   | 03/12/2023 | 18:18:00 |
|      1 | 03/12/2023 21:12:00 | 23.99   | 03/12/2023 | 21:12:00 |
|      1 | 03/12/2023 22:11:00 | 23.77   | 03/12/2023 | 22:11:00 |
|      2 | 03/12/2023 05:06:00 | 27.75   | 03/12/2023 | 05:06:00 |
|      2 | 03/12/2023 08:42:00 | 27.03   | 03/12/2023 | 08:42:00 |
|      2 | 03/12/2023 16:13:00 | 23.66   | 03/12/2023 | 16:13:00 |
|      2 | 03/12/2023 17:12:00 | 23.55   | 03/12/2023 | 17:12:00 |
|      2 | 03/12/2023 17:41:00 | 23.44   | 03/12/2023 | 17:41:00 |
|      3 | 03/12/2023 06:06:00 | 27.63   | 03/12/2023 | 06:06:00 |
|      3 | 03/12/2023 10:46:00 | 27.32   | 03/12/2023 | 10:46:00 |
|      3 | 03/12/2023 12:26:00 | 26.99   | 03/12/2023 | 12:26:00 |
|      3 | 03/12/2023 20:02:00 | 26.6    | 03/12/2023 | 20:02:00 |
|      3 | 03/12/2023 21:22:00 | 26.55   | 03/12/2023 | 21:22:00 |
|      3 | 03/12/2023 22:11:00 | 26.38   | 03/12/2023 | 22:11:00 |
|      4 | 03/12/2023 06:36:00 | 27.45   | 03/12/2023 | 06:36:00 |
|      4 | 03/12/2023 09:26:00 | 26.45   | 03/12/2023 | 09:26:00 |
|      4 | 03/12/2023 11:26:00 | 25.45   | 03/12/2023 | 11:26:00 |
|      4 | 03/12/2023 15:16:00 | 24.45   | 03/12/2023 | 15:16:00 |
|      4 | 03/12/2023 23:02:00 | 23.45   | 03/12/2023 | 23:02:00 |
|      1 | 03/12/2023 23:00:00 | 28.73   | 03/12/2023 | 23:00:00 |
|      1 | 04/12/2023 10:36:00 | 27.09   | 04/12/2023 | 10:36:00 |
|      1 | 04/12/2023 18:18:00 | 25.09   | 04/12/2023 | 18:18:00 |
|      1 | 04/12/2023 21:12:00 | 23.99   | 04/12/2023 | 21:12:00 |
|      1 | 04/12/2023 23:11:00 | 23      | 04/12/2023 | 23:11:00 |
+--------+---------------------+---------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Can you update with desired results. Thanks

Comment: @DavideBacci updated, thanks

Comment: Why are there two `device = 1` in your desired results? Do you want them grouped by device  and date?

Comment: @SamNseir correct. The results need to be grouped by device, but also by date. We also need to consider that charging can start the previous day. (I've correct the sample data to reflect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calendar table as follows:

```
Calendar = CALENDAR(DATE(YEAR(MIN('Table'[timestamp])),1,1), DATE(YEAR(MAX('Table'[timestamp])),12,31))
```

Create a one-to-many relationship to your table:

[image]

Create a table visual and drop in calendar.date and your id:

[image]

Add the following measures:

```
voltage_high = MAX('Table'[voltage])

voltage_low = MIN('Table'[voltage])

timestamp_high = 
VAR x = [voltage_high]
RETURN
CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[timestamp]),  FILTER('Table', 'Table'[voltage] = x))

timestamp_low = 
VAR x = [voltage_low]
RETURN
CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[timestamp]),  FILTER('Table', 'Table'[voltage] = x))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you. When I apply it to my data, if there is an irregular charge time, the voltage_high can occur after the voltage_low. 
Is there a way to conditionally reference the previous day's voltage/timestamp high values in this case?

Comment: Hard to say without sample data and expected results. As this works with your sample data, I suggest marking as solved and asking a new question with new data and results.

Comment: I believe desired results in the question were updated as Davide Bacci posted this answer. @Damo - see alternative answer.

Comment: You are correct; it was unfair timing, so I accepted the answer based on the version Davide was working on.

Answer (score 0):

**PowerQuery solution** - this can handle multiple charges per day.

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("fdRRjsIwDATQq6z4RiWxnbT1VVDvfw1aLXbceITED4yeaKaO3+9HfTwfhV+VXlSI/8qu3LWU81dal5Vv6fXF8uOZbC3Rln22niO76fn5tw1Zy4GlqpW+lpc9Wc+RJa3V7boma/llaeqqaQldtdSV5chuKjS6yj1bDmztWtmfuffUleXIrrGrlp7Zc2xldCUCrHhXPJ23x656Pm8PXU32nBsZlin9r+XIkpLZDmbDc2CpaCG3qWaPEa1Kg+aaPUc2jGRfePs5kpJqDldQ8kj2cAVnu8eqgN1DVZM9H8htA9ZzZJtWs4Ks5cASj1fEwHqOrv51R752A6vOc7fyc9XJfSSnVRcsWHU3m1adxLlKq07uczWtOonnHasuQQuP4wM=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [device = _t, timestamp = _t, voltage = _t, date = _t, time = _t]),
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"device", Int64.Type}, {"timestamp", type datetime}, {"voltage", type number}, {"date", type date}, {"time", type time}}),
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "timestamp_high", each
    let
      thisDevice = [device],
      thisTimestamp = [timestamp],
      prevDeviceRow = Table.Last(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [device] = thisDevice and [timestamp] < thisTimestamp), [voltage = -1]),
      preVoltage = prevDeviceRow[voltage],
      result = if [voltage] > preVoltage then [timestamp] else null
    in
      result,
    type nullable datetime),
  #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"timestamp_high"}),
  #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"device", "timestamp_high"}, { {"timestamp_low", each List.Last([timestamp]), type nullable datetime}, {"voltage_high", each List.First([voltage]), type nullable number}, {"voltage_low", each List.Last([voltage]), type nullable number}})
in
  #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

**Note** - see how the last row matches your desired result.

---

**DAX solution** - this can handle multiple charges per day.

In your existing table, create the following Calculated Columns (in order):

```
// you can hide this column from report view
group_start = 
  var thisDevice = [device]
  var thisTS = [timestamp]
  var dFilter = FILTER('Device', 'Device'[device] = thisDevice && 'Device'[timestamp] < thisTS)
  var prevRow = TOPN(1, dFilter, 'Device'[timestamp], DESC)
  var prevV = CALCULATE(MAX('Device'[voltage]), prevRow)
  return IF(ISBLANK(prevV) || [voltage] > prevV, thisTS)

// this is the important column
group = 
  var thisDevice = [device]
  var thisTS = [timestamp]
  var dFilter = FILTER('Device', 'Device'[device] = thisDevice && 'Device'[timestamp] <= thisTS)
  return CALCULATE(MAX('Device'[group_start]), dFilter)
```

`group` will "group" the rows so that other calculations will become possible.

From here you can choose to add further Calculated Columns like:

```
timestamp_high = [group]


timestamp_low = 
  var gpFilter = ALLEXCEPT('Device', 'Device'[device], 'Device'[group])
  RETURN CALCULATE(MAX('Device'[timestamp]), gpFilter)


voltage_high = 
  var gpFilter = ALLEXCEPT('Device', 'Device'[device], 'Device'[group])
  RETURN CALCULATE(MAX('Device'[voltage]), gpFilter)


voltage_low = 
  var gpFilter = ALLEXCEPT('Device', 'Device'[device], 'Device'[group])
  RETURN CALCULATE(MIN('Device'[voltage]), gpFilter)
```

Or you may choose to create a new Calculated Table like so:

```
Device Summary = 
  SUMMARIZE(
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
      'Device'[device],
      'Device'[group],
      "timestamp_high", MIN('Device'[timestamp]),
      "timestamp_low", MAX('Device'[timestamp]),
      "voltage_high", MAX('Device'[timestamp]),
      "voltage_low", MIN('Device'[timestamp])
    ),
    Device[device], [timestamp_high], [timestamp_low], [voltage_high], [voltage_low]
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Sam. Unfortunately, when I point this at my (imported) large dataset, it doesn't load the results in PowerQuery. It just continually shows a loading prompt.

Comment: Approximately how many rows? And is the DataSource SQL? Perhaps query folding is slowing it down. You could try adding a step before with `PreventQueryFolding = Table.StopFolding([YOUR-PREVIOUS-STEP]),`. I've also updated the answer above with a dax solution.